# react-native-external-display library is not supporting in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

react-native-external-display library not supporting in expo app. facing error null is not an object (evaluating 'RNExternalDisplayEvent.SCREEN_INFO'). I would like to use a expo in the device which has two display screens so I need to display my code based on display screen.
[image] . Please support me with your suggestions If any other library which will support my requirement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found any other library that supports an external display for React Native. Therefore using Expo may not be the best choice.

You could eject expo and then add the react-native-external-display library, which may require you to fix some errors. Alternatively you could start a new project without expo and add the library.